# Where to add custom fields to entity?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am using SonataAdmin and have a dozen entities and one controller. The majority of the CMS is simply displaying the entity fields as-is from the database into my views. I would like to add some custom fields to my entities from which the data would span multiple fields (meaning on my Car entity, I would like to also query the Driver and License entities.)

Here's an example of my Car and Driver entities:

```
<?php

namespace Scholar\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Car
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Car", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="driverId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $driverId;

  // ...

}
```

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Driver
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Driver", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Driver
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

  // ...

}
```

and how I add the fields to be displayed for each entity (by extending Admin):

```
<?php

namespace Scholar\AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class CarAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->add('sync');
        $collection->remove('create');
        $collection->remove('delete');
    }

    /**
     * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('firstName');
    }

    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->addIdentifier('firstName')
        // ...
    }
```

I would like to add a `numberOfDrivers` field to the Car entity. I have the query working (using `queryBuilder`.) I obviously have to query the Car and Driver entity (and some others.) My question is, to add this custom field to the Car entity, where is the best place to put the method that does the query across multiple entities, and then how do I add this to my dataFilters and let it be accessible in my `$listMapper`

so that I may do something like this to display the `numberOfDrivers` on the Car admin page and allow it to be sortable:

```
    /**
     * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('firstName');
            ->add('numberOfDrivers');
    }

    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->addIdentifier('firstName')
            ->addIdentifier('numberOfDrivers')
        // ...
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there more information I can provide to get answers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach would be to let the ORM do the work. If I understand correctly a car can have multiple drivers and a driver can drive multiple cars. So you have a standard many-to-many relation.

So in your Car orm metadata you define (e.g. Car.orm.xml):

```
<many-to-many field="drivers" target-entity="Driver">
  <join-table name="car2driver">
    <join-columns>
      <join-column name="driver_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </join-columns>
    <inverse-join-columns>
      <join-column name="car_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </inverse-join-columns>
  </join-table>
</many-to-many>
```

In the constructor of your Car entity you init:

```
private $drivers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->drivers = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Add a new field

```
private $numberOfDrivers;
```

with the respective getter. The getter should look like this:

```
public function getNumberOfDrivers()
{
   $this->drivers->count();
}
```

You should now be able to use 'numberOfDrivers' as described above.

Comment: This answer is precisely how I went about it but what about for more complex examples, such as getting ONLY the count() of drivers that are insured by "AcmeInsure"? I understand it would be something like $this->drivers->where('insurance', 'AcmeInsure')->count(); // or looping through drivers manually, etc. but when this gets nested too deep or I have Entities that have NO association but I still want them included in the match/query, how would this work?

Comment: I accepted this as the right answer because it's elegant and works most of the time. I'm still having problems creating a custom aggregate field that fetches data from multiple tables

Comment: Thanks :) . Depending on your architecture complex queries and stuff would be handled in Repository-classes.
Say you want to build a query for drivers you create a DriverRepository.php where you access the entity manager with `$this->getEntityManager()` . See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)